# Script to replace all symbolic links to a target to point to another target (in the same directory)

Tags: bash, shell-script, symlink

Given the following contrived example:

```
$ mkdir -p a/b && touch a/b/original-target && touch a/b/new-target
$ mkdir -p c1/c2 && cd c1/c2 && ln -s ../../a/b/original-target && cd -
$ mkdir -p d1/d2/d3 && cd d1/d2/d3 && ln -s ../../../a/b/original-target && cd -
$ tree .
.
├── a
│   └── b
│       ├── new-target
│       └── original-target
├── c1
│   └── c2
│       └── original-target -> ../../a/b/original-target
└── d1
    └── d2
        └── d3
            └── original-target -> ../../../a/b/original-target
```

How do I replace all symlinks to `original-target` to symlinks to `new-target`. You may assume that both the original and the new target live in the same directory (as is the case in the contrived example above). The symlinks have to use relative paths.

Comment: Can the answer assume that _all_ symlinks in the directory tree currently point to `a/b/original-target`, or does the script need to check for that (and process _only_ those links that currently point to `a/b/original-target`)?

Comment: @Scott: my particular case demands the latter

Comment: So... not `mv original-target new-target`?

Comment: @mikeserv sadly no. Reason is that I want to preserve both (the new-target is actually itself a symlink to the original-target and I want other directories to refer to the symlink as opposed to the original-target itself).

Comment: wait... what??? Man... *why*? symbolic links are a terrible long-term solution to any problem - that kind of indirected indirection only multiplies problems - problems like this one. You should be looking at `mount`s, in my not-humble-enough opinion *(sorry for coming on strong - but I *hate** symlinks)* - set the whole thing up in `/etc/fstab`. symlinks are good for temporary file references - but, as I see it, they should then be discarded as *temporary*. You have a perfectly good pathname - Why link to a link of a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using bash, so I would use `globstar` to loop through all directories at once with `**`. After that all what is left is to play a little bit with `readlink`, `realpath`, etc:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in c1/** d1/**; do
    if [[ -h "$file" ]]; then
        if [[ "$(readlink -f "$file")" == "$(realpath a/b/original-target)" ]]; then
            ln -sf "$(dirname "$(readlink "$file")")"/new-target "$(dirname "$file")" && rm -f "$file"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`pax` can be *really* useful in these cases. In fact it would be easier if I could discover a `pax` that does the `-o listopt=...` option [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html) but, despite my looking, I've yet to find one that does. I use the one mirabilos maintains - the BSD `pax` *(`mirabipax`?)* - which is probably the one most others do as far as I know. Anyway you get to regex filenames - and file-listings. For example:

```
(set -e; mkdir -p a/b c1/c2 d1/d2/d3
touch a/b/original-target a/b/new-target
cd c1/c2; ln -s ../../a/b/original-target
cd ../../d1/d2/d3; ln -s ../../../a/b/original-target)
```

That makes your tree. Now I'll list it:

```
pax -ws'|\(\..*/original-target.*\)*.*|\1|' ././ | 
pax -cvs'|\(.*\)/original|\1/new|p' \
     '././a/b/original-target' '*/original-target?*'
```

Which prints...

```
././d1/d2/d3/original-target >> ././d1/d2/d3/new-target
lrwxrwxrwx  1 mikeserv mikeserv         0 Dec  7 18:17 ././d1/d2/d3/new-target => ../../../a/b/new-target
././c1/c2/original-target >> ././c1/c2/new-target
lrwxrwxrwx  1 mikeserv mikeserv         0 Dec  7 18:14 ././c1/c2/new-target => ../../a/b/new-target
```

Ok, so the first `pax` writes a `ustar` archive to `stdout`. The `-s` regex arg I handed it is most often used for changing filenames in stream - as I do here w/ the second `pax` - but with a trick or two it can also be used to filter files added to the archive in the first place.

You see, any filename which winds up empty following application of the `-s` arg is specified to be dropped from the archive completely. So I use a regex that will match every filename but also remove every character from each that doesn't match the pattern saved in `\1`. This is necessary because while you can easily select files within an archive based on a pattern, this is not the case when `-w`riting the archive - that depends on shell globs and so does not recurse.

Still, the regex as written will still get `/original-target` followed by any character, and so, on the other end one of the patterns I `-c`omplement in my selection when listing the archive is `*/original-target?*` - which will drop it there. Even that is not perfect - I mean, maybe there are links you have which contain that pattern twice, but ... well, it is what it is - and it's pretty good. It can be handled with further testing along the same lines. Anyway, I also `-c`omplement a match to `././a/b/original-file` itself - and so that is dropped from the list output as well.

In list mode - which is what `pax` does when it does not `-r`ead or `-w`rite - `pax` lists *verbosely* - in `ls -l` format - including any soft link targets like `link => target` - but only after applying any applicable `-s` args. Those very same `-s` args are printed regardless of the `-v` when `-s|...|...|p` the `p` modifier is applied in the following format:

> "%s>>%s\n", *original pathname*, *new pathname*

So above we get the listings separated with the `././` which wouldn't otherwise appear. Now that makes things really easy, as I hope you will agree. I'll leave it to the reader to decide how one might apply that sort of data with `ln` - it should be fairly simple - but *you shouldn't even need to do that*.

In fact, `pax` is spec'd to allow you to alter the archive at `r`ead or `w`rite time with cli options for altering such things as user, group, linkdata, filename, file-source, etc. These are incredibly powerful file parsing tools - but the closest I've come to `pax` that implements them is GNU `tar` and only in part. I haven't found any means of affecting a header's file types - though you should be able to do this to some degree - with cli options, even if it isn't terribly difficult to with a regex on the archive itself. There is a header field for this stuff:

> ... 2 - Represents a symbolic link. The contents of the symbolic link shall be stored in the *linkname* field.

Another thing I really want a `pax` to do is `-o listopt=...`. Here's a snippet from the spec's examples section:

> Using the option:

```
-o listopt="%M %(atime)T %(size)D %(name)s"
```

> ...overrides the default output description in Standard Output and instead writes:

```
-rw-rw--- Jan 12 15:53 2003 1492 /usr/foo/bar
```

> Using the options:

```
-o listopt='%L\t%(size)D\n%.7' \
-o listopt='(name)s\n%(atime)T\n%T'
```

> ...overrides the default output description in Standard Output and instead writes:

```
/usr/foo/bar -> /tmp   1492
/usr/fo
Jan 12 15:53 1991
Jan 31 15:53 2003
```

So if you stumble across a `pax` that does that... well, you know who's looking.